# Want to learn 360 'adventures' like the link, similar to Google Street View

Tags: three.js, 360-degrees

I'm trying to learn how to do some 360 image edits like the site below, and I'm really just looking for any information to point me in the right direction. All I was told by the site owners was "we cant give away anything, but three.js".

Can anyone else help point me in the right direction. I've googled it and its basically sending me in circles.

I just want to be able to move from location to location like Street view and add pointers/annotations.

https://www.xplorit.com/long-beach

Comment: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: I get it, I dreaded asking here, but I've literally been re-searching this for awhile now. I can make some geometric cubes. There seems to be little to know knowledge base about one step further without paying for a vendor

Comment: Maybe you should visit one of the Web or Javascript rooms at [chat.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/). It is usually fast and loose in the rooms. You can ask as many off-topic questions you like. I often jump into a room while zero'ing in on a problem.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks

Comment: I think this is one of the problems with Stack Overflow. Chat is a good resource while researching a problem at a time when the questions are broad and open-ended. But the site does not educate users to utilize it. Instead they throw folks into the pond and expect them to swim. I don't know how to improve the awareness and education for this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think like most people, they just stumbled upon StackOverflow, i never got an explanation, education, or anything. I asked someone a coding question like "hey do you know how to (blank)" and they said "check stackoverflow".

I didnt even know there was a chat section. I know there are other version (like android, raspberry pi, etc), but I often think of this as a good catch all starting point.maybe add one of those 'chat' boxes to the question page like other websites

Comment: such broad wide questions better to ask on the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/)

Comment: that page actually helps a lot

Answer (score 2):

Using THREE.js you can set your panoramic photo as the texture on a sphere... You have to flip the .side of the material so it only draws the inside of the sphere.. then use the OrbitController to let the user zoom in/out/rotate the view..

Check out this demo here, and see if you can drag one of your equirectangular images on it:
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html